# Adding addition information to API Gateway response

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

Is there a way to add an additional property to the API Gateway response in CDK?
In my case, I want to add a property `response_id` to the response body from API Gateway in CDK.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the data transformations section in the documentation.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/rest-api-data-transformations.html

Simple example:

```
api.root.addMethod(
      'GET',
      new MockIntegration({
        integrationResponses: [
          {
            statusCode: '200',
            responseParameters: {
              'method.response.body.response_id': 'integration.response.header.response_id', // The mapping
            }
          }
        ]
      }),
      {
        methodResponses: [
          {
            statusCode: '200',
            responseParameters: {
              'method.response.body.response_id': true // Required to map a value to this
            },
          }
        ]
      }
    );
```

Make sure that you map an actual integration response parameter, so if you map it to a header an the integration is lambda: the lambda should return the header.

Comment: Is this the same `response_id` that api-gateway will return even when the integration returns an error? For example, in the case of an SQS-integration, it does happen sometimes that SQS returns an error, but api-gateway will still return a `response_id`.

Comment: Unless you can provide me with the documentation link to this property provided by AWS, I think this is some custom property you should implement yourself if you need it.

I know AWS makes use of requestId properties, but I have never heard of a response_id property...

Comment: My bad, I meant `request_id` instead of `response_id`.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference
You can use this in the mapping expression: $context.requestId